# How to add new fields and inherit old(predecessor) fields' value on Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to update the name of some fields, is there any way to do it since we can't simply changed their field name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to update the name of some fields

For this issue,the created work item field name cannot be modified.This is stated in the official document.You can refer to the **Note** part of this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops#add-a-field) .

> How to add new fields and inherit old(predecessor) fields' value on
>   Azure Devops?

For this issue,you can add a rule to the work item to achieve inheritance values.

Condition: When No value is defined for the new field

Actions: Then Copy the value from the old filed to new field

[image]

With this setting, when your new field has no value, it will automatically copy the value of the field you specified to the new field.

Comment: I want to permanently copy value of old field to new field, and adjust new field value only